# Javascript/Node.js async loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm having trouble with the async nature of node in general.  Can someone help me with this block of code.   For various reasons I can only insert 1 row at a time into the database I am working with.  And actually, it would be even better if I could add a short delay to only insert 1 row per second into the database.

Here is a short section of my js code.

```
console.log('*** Inserting Records ***')
insertPromises = []
_.each(dbRecords, function (item) {
    var insertItem = buildRecord(item)
    insertPromises.push(conn.create(insertItem))
})
Promise.all(insertPromises).then(function (res) {
    _.each(res, function (item) {
        if (!item.success) {
            console.log("### Error ### " + JSON.stringify(res[i].errors))
        }
    })
    console.log('*** Inserted ' + res.length + ' Contacts')
})
```

My main question is how can I force the loop to wait for the conn.create promise to resolve before continuing the loop?   And is there a way to slow the loop to 1 iteration per second?

Comment: was that answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the recursion code posted above, you could check the [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) model.

An example of using this would be:

```
async function processRecords(dbRecords) {

    for (let item of dbRecords) {
        try {
            let insertItem = buildRecord(item)
            await conn.create(insertItem)
            await delay(1000)
        } catch (e) {
           //handle error...
        }
   }

}

function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

processRecords(dbRecords)
```

This is es7 code and you need [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/) compiler to transform it.

It is probably better to use something like this if you find hard to keep up with promises and you want to stick with sync-like code.

Comment: you don't need babel to transform it; that syntax is fully supported in nodejs 7.6 and above. :)

Comment: nice, thanks for mentioning that! But the question doesn't mention the nodejs version he is using, so maybe babel is required!

Comment: nice...  I like this approach but am getting UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning.   My code is nearly exact what you have in your answer.   fyi - it's working perfectly...  just throws the error when it exits the loop.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to keep track of an "insert count", that is, the current number of successfully inserted records. This will be your array pointer. Use a method to create each, individual promise and increment your "insert count" by 1 on each successful response.

```
let insertCount = 0;

function insertNextRecord() {
    conn.create(buildRecord(dbRecords[insertCount]).then(function(res){
        insertCount += 1;
        insertNextRecord();
    }).catch(function() {
        console.log('Error while inserting record ' + insertCount);
    });
}

insertNextRecord();
```

**This is not tested and I'm making several assumptions about the code you're not showing.**

This example assumes:

- `dbRecords` is an array
- `conn.create` returns a promise object

To explicitly add a delay, you could use a timeout within the `then` method like so:

```
let insertCount = 0;

function insertNextRecord() {
    conn.create(buildRecord(dbRecords[insertCount]).then(function(res){
        insertCount += 1;
        setTimeout(function() {
            insertNextRecord();
        }, 500);
    }).catch(function() {
        console.log('Error while inserting record ' + insertCount);
    });
}

insertNextRecord();
```

I should also say it's unfortunate that you have to do it this way. This will be very slow when dealing with many inserts.

Comment: It doesn't function like the current code, it has recursion, this block will run each db query sequentially. To add delay, someone could simply add a setTimeout in the inner insertNextRecord()

Comment: No, you're current code uses Promise.all which waits for all of the promises in `insertPromises` to resolve before resolving itself. In other words, that promise wouldn't resolve until all insert requests are complete. The example I've provided waits for the current request to resolve before moving to the next. You don't want to explicitly account for a "delay" - that is known as a race condition. You just want to know when request '1' is done and then make request '2' - and when request 'B' is done then make request '3'...and so on.